# Ubuntu 22.04 - Prevent Firefox from .deb file Installation version to Automatic updating Snap file installation!

Tags: gnome, package-management, updates, firefox, gnome-shell

for integration with the GNOME Shell center I need Firefox to be installed in the operating system with the `.deb` extension instead of the automatic via SNAP Firefox file.
The problem of Firefox under SNAP file extension is that, it does not fully integrate with the Operating System, this is because (for example) a function that Firefox loses is that of managing Gnome Extensions to be integrated through GNOME Shell.

Now, I uninstalled Firefox with the command `sudo snap remove firefox` and replace it with the .deb version file, everything works perfectly, but as soon as there is a new version of Firefox, the software updates automatically and uninstall the installation `.deb` file extension to replacing it with Firefox under SNAP file extension.

My question is, how can I prevent this automatic installation of Firefox and stop the new upgrade under the SNAP file extension?

I would like that Firefox will keep automatically update to the new version, but under the same package extension `.deb` file.

Comment: Try this https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 or this https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/

Comment: This is directly addressed in the [22.04 release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668): "*The Firefox snap does not support the NativeMessaging protocol 47 yet but this feature is planned to be added soon. This means for instance that installing GNOME Shell extensions from Firefox won’t work. As a workaround, you can try the gnome-shell-extension-manager app.*"

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the command `sudo apt get firefox` from installing the snap version of Firefox, add an APT preference that prohibits installation of the default `firefox` package of Ubuntu:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/firefox-no-snap.pref
Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=Ubuntu*
Pin-Priority: -1
EOF
```

This specifically prohibits installation of the default `firefox` package, which starting with Ubuntu 22.04, automatically triggers the install of the snap version. You still can install any `firefox` package from an external PPA, and you could still install the snap version through `snap install firefox`.